# Should I delete my (unaccepted) answer to a very esoteric question?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

I proposed an answer to an esoteric question to a tag that doesn't get a ton of traffic.  The asker didn't accept the answer; in fact he almost seems to want to have a debate in the comments why it cannot work.  Now, I **know** it works because I've done it -- or at least what I think he's asking.

Bottom line is I don't think he'll ever accept my code or suggestions, and since it's an esoteric answer to an esoteric question, I have to wonder if this answer will prove fruitful for others in the future...

Here's the page: [question being discussed.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44412745/how-can-i-pass-a-structure-down-a-tree-i-e-an-inherited-attribute-when-using)  Being new to this, I don't know what course is best for the site and especially for the community as a whole.  I do know that I don't want to let a debate sprout up in the comments, as that's not good for anyone.  Can I get some advice please?

Comment: The easiest way to prevent the comments from dragging out, without deleting your answer (if you decide you want to keep it for posterity), is to simply not pursue the topic.

Comment: Does it matter if it's not accepted?

Comment: Perhaps reality has answered my own question.  Someone just upvoted my answer.  I'll leave it and abandon the discussion.  Thanks folks.

Comment: Sometimes your answer is never accepted - don't worry about it. Even for esoteric topics, you will eventually get upvotes if the answer is good.

Comment: @JLH That's the [meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect) :-)

Comment: *"or at least what I think he's asking"* - I have to ask, does that imply you weren't sure what the true question was when you posted the answer?

Comment: The asker is free not to accept an answer because they don't think it solves their problem. If you can't convince them otherwise (and they can't convince *you* otherwise) then that's the end of it. There's no reason to delete unless *you* believe the answer is not useful (possibly because you've been convinced by others). The asker doesn't have the exclusive right to determine which answers are useful - they only get to decide which answer is most useful to them (if any).

Comment: Reading the question and answer, it seems that he is looking for a more scalable approach-- something your solution does not give him.  Hence, he is not accepting your answer.

Comment: I'm interested in a scalable approach but the answers don't explain HOW to do what they suggest. JLH said, "I simple append to a static List<>...in each visitor". But where is that static list defined? It can't be global or an instance variable because that won't support recursion. You need to be able create such lists in visitors and so as to pass them DOWN to other visitors. This "inherited attribute approach" is a standard paradigm described in many classic compiler design books. See for example, Compiler Design Theory (Lewis Rosenkrantz Stearn) or Aho's "Dragon book". It is NOT esoteric.

Comment: _"I have to wonder if this answer will prove fruitful for others in the future"_ -- do you? Really? Have to wonder? You seem to be asking the obverse of [this similarly poorly-researched](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350398/is-it-worth-answering-an-old-question-that-already-has-20-answers) Meta question. Bottom line: if your question adds value to the site, keep it. If it doesn't, don't. You don't need to ask a question on Meta to know that. I'm thinking maybe I should have to wonder if I too should follow-up all my unvoted answers with a question on meta to game the meta effect.

Comment: @PeterDuniho . At the time I wrote this, I did not know.  Now I do.  And I had never heard of any meta effect before this lively discussion.  I was essentially a non-user up until a few weeks ago.