# Is it worth answering an old question that already has 20+ answers?

Tags: discussion, old-questions

I have an answer to an old question which has 20+ established answers already. I feel my answer might be better than most of the existing answers, but I'm concerned that the existing answers will get more upvotes regardless if my answer is better, due to the fact that they will get **orders of magnitude more views**. (Who scrolls to the bottom of a 20+ answers page?!)

Should I invest time in writing an answer, or is my effort better spent elsewhere?

**Edit**: To clarify, by "worth it" I mean does an effort like this make a bigger impact (not in terms of rep but being more helpful to fellow programmers) than spending an equal amount of time on more low hanging fruit.

<sup>*(Sharing my own findings in an answer below, but am genuinly interested in other peoples experiences too!)*</sup>

Comment: Yes, it is worth it to add new good answers to any old question.

Comment: As Technology changes and new posibilities occure, it could be very helpful if you have a similar Problem and find next to the old answer an updated one with a new way to resolve it, which was mit even possible back then. Worth it

Comment: If the technology is completely updated and the answer is completely outdated, then make an answer. for small updates, edit the accepted answer

Comment: Unfortunately you have now distorted your "experiment" with the meta effect.

Comment: @Luuklag, yes. I'm well aware of this. This is why I waited 1.5 years to post this. I have not made any effort in promoting the answer other than that I put a link to it in my profile. The experiment is pretty much over as of this post.

Comment: @SagarV: I would not update *first*, I'd start by commenting on the existing answer to prod the answerer; they might not be agreeable, in which case a new answer is warranted.

Comment: @aloobe Based on your definition of "worth", the answer IMHO would be "no".

Comment: @torazaburo, care to elaborate your thoughts? Is it simply that 20 answers is enough and posting answer number 3 on a newer question would make a bigger impact?

Comment: That's one of the reasons why I think ordering by (more or less) only reputation can be problematic since it gives a large disadvantage to new (and potentially better) answers.

Comment: For users that are on the lower part of the experience scale, like myself, pretty much all answers are useful. I have learned something from all or almost all answers to my questions.

Comment: I've noticed a definite problem on stackoverflow in which sometimes the accepted and/or top answer is crucially worse, bad, or even dangerous compared to a lower-ranked answer. This is almost always because the bad answer was the best for awhile, then a much better answer was posted later. More rarely, the accepted/top answer was always bad, but the OP and early upvoters didn't know any better. There should be a mechanism for addressing this. Or is there one already? Raw upvotes doesn't seem to cut it because too few people scroll past #1.

Answer (score 65):

I faced this situation 1.5 years ago on this question:

[In Java, difference between default, public, protected, and private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497)

and thought, hey, let's make this an experiment.

I put some effort into it and posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33627846) and then kept an eye on the progress.

Today I got a gold badge for it and I thought I'd share my findings.

Here's the chart of the number of votes each answer has had since I posted my answer. This chart includes the top answer by David Segonds:

[image]

Since I posted my answer, David Segonds has in average received **1.9 upvotes per day**, while I have received **0.17 upvotes per day** on mine. I'm obviously biased, but I consider my answer to be of slightly higher quality, and I assume the numbers are due to the fact that only a small percentage scroll past the top answer.

Clearly I'll never catch up... or?

### Perhaps there's still hope...

Dropping David Segonds answer from the chart declutters the image: [image]

I've climbed from pos 20 to pos 4.

I obviously still have a long long way to go, but I'm thinking that it might accelerate slightly as the answer climbes closer to the top. I see a vague trend the past two months but it's still almost insignificant.

Should the post ever reach second place I think there could be an "underdog" effect and it might just take off.

### So, is it worth the effort?

Still unclear as of today. Judging from the votes, it looks like I've helped <strike>~100</strike> more than 100 users out there which feels good, but over 1.5 years, that's a small impact. For a question like this, I'd say it's still worth it, but for a more obscure question, I doubt it.

**Update**: After reading through the comments, other answers and statistics that has been mentioned, I'm convinced that it's worth it. Maybe not *as worth it* as I had originally hoped, but I still think the effort was well spent. I think this is due to the nature of the question though. The ROI may come in 3-4 years, which is ok for Java fundamentals (I believe Java will be the COBOL of 2050). Had it been a new and shiny front-end library there's a risk that the tech is dead and forgotten before ROI.

I'll continue to keep an eye on it and regardless of how it goes, I'll try to update this post in a year or so.

Comment: I think having the y in log scale could show something interesting.

Comment: I have a somewhat similar experience with my answer on [Rails redirect with https](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1662262/660921), which I added five years after it was asked (and answered). At +18 it didn't do as well as well as your +100, but that's probably because it's a less common question. It did a lot better than I had expected.

Comment: Don't forget your answer is likely to have been seen by people who don't vote. So it could well have helped significantly more than 100 people.

Comment: _So, is it worth the effort?_ The sain answer:  Yes, absolutely. Because your goal should be to share knowledge, not gaining virtual reputation points. The SO answer: No, it's not, because an answer having multiple upvotes will stay on top way too long - even if it's outdated and not good anymore, but your good answer has very little chance of being recognized by the audience your answer would deserve - folks only read the first answer that solves the problem!

Comment: You question if it was worth it? Seriously? Even for you, who is in the top 0.02% for reputation, this question has more up-votes than 99% of your 3,056 answers. How could you consider it not worth it, by any metric?

Comment: @baao, my goal is to help as many as possible. With that in mind, the effort might be better spent on questions that have not received as much attention yet.

Comment: @Makyen, it's not about the rep, it's about the impact. It's not worth 1-2 hours of my time if "no one" is going to see it. Then I'd rather spend that time answering other newer questions.

Comment: Judging "worth" by votes is a bit dubious. You have to consider all of the anonymous traffic that we get, coming straight from Google and other search engines, who aren't logged in and therefore can't vote or indicate that your answer was helpful to them in anyway. Yet, if you know that it is in fact a helpful answer, or even the *best* answer, then you should *definitely* post it, because you know it must be helping some of those people. Furthermore, even if it just helped one person, wouldn't that be "worth" it? Only you can say, but I'm personally not here for the fake points.

Comment: @CodyGray, I think it took me 2h or so to produce that answer, so no, I don't think it's worth it if it's seen by one person. I'm not after the rep, but the rep is a reasonable proxy for impact. Googlers still land at the top of the page and need to scroll for quite a while to get to answer number 20. Doesn't matter if you have an account or not.

Comment: When I said "by any metric", I was trying to imply that reputation was not the only reason it was worth it. Your next highest voted answer (score: 102) is on a question with 3 answers and 56,934 views. That's an up-vote rate of 558 views per up-vote. Assuming the same rate applies to the answer we're talking about, then that's 57,492 people which have viewed your answer, of the 1,194,718 views which the question has had total. As you get more votes the percentage of viewers who see your answer will be higher, and you will have more impact. So, your impact will only go up from here. (continued)

Comment: I was going to compare your answer to others which you made around the same time, and later. However, what I found was that the answer we're talking about is your most recent answer. The one you posted next most recently is on a question with 354 views and has gotten 8 votes. To have the same number of views as you've gotten on the answer we're talking about, you would have to post 162 answers comparable to the one you posted prior to this one. That would mean that if you can keep up a rate of 0.74 minutes per answer, you could have the same impact as you had by spending 2h on your answer.

Comment: That's interesting. So, one key metric to answering a question like this is probably something like views per upvote. Unfortunately there's no way to find historical view data (that I know of) so it's hard to do a full scale analysis. For this particular post however, I've [kept tabs](https://pastebin.com/raw/A9VEtfeJ). As you point out I currently have 558 (question-)views per upvote on [that other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7378472). On this answer it's 4568 views per upvote. So by this metric the other answer is still better. It will be interesting to see if this answer caches up.

Comment: @aioobe probably it will, but these things can take a very long time. I consider that a good thing about Stack Overflow; if you for-go short term gains, you will generally see long-term gains and thus the effort is always worth it. Speaking from the perspective of a consumer: too often do I get my worth from a late-game zero or one upvote answer because it presents a modern way of doing things. I always make the effort to upvote them, but I may be in a minority there.

Comment: The difference in views per up-vote between the two answers could be accounted for just by the limited number of viewers which scrolled down far enough to see your answer to the question (i.e. a small percentage scrolled down through the answers to your late one). While views per up-vote is an interesting metric, the overall issue that you're asking is if it's more time-effective wrt. helping an absolute number of people. Thus, you must take into account the views per time-period, not just question views per up-vote, when comparing two answers (and the time they took to write).

Comment: You've spent time on 3,000+ answers. Very few of them will get anywhere close to that number of views of your answer. If you goal is to maximize the absolute number of people that see the answer and are helped by it, then you should *only* answer questions which are already proved to get a large number of views, rather than spend time helping people whose questions are very unlikely to have such large general appeal. That's assuming you have something to contribute to such questions beyond what's already there (i.e. are actually helping).

Comment: Right. So it's in part about views and in part about the helping "delta" that answer number 21 provides. Granted I will get more views on this answer in the long run. Hopefully the delta against the existing 20 answers is enough of a "multiplier" to make it wortwhile.

Comment: I've had a [similar situation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16233919/1000608), and I've climbed to position 3 (and steadily catching up to pos 2 and 1).

Answer (score 34):

If you are genuinely interested in Stack Overflow's ideals, and you think you can answer better than what's already there, then those two factors are more than enough justification for posting your answer.

If you are less idealistic and more pragmatic, then it's probably not worth it. If you still feel that what you have to say is valuable enough to devote some time articulating it and sharing it, I'm guessing you'd do better making a blog post.

I suppose you could also try "gamier" methods, such as self-answering a new question. Sure, it would likely be closed as a duplicate, but your answer would then be at or near the top; and if you've formulated the question and answer well enough, there is a chance that the new question could be anointed the canonical one, and the older one closed as a duplicate of yours. Even if not, the linkages and search traffic may make such an answer more visible than a deeply buried one.

Comment: IMHO, this is the only valid answer. The only reason to add content to Stack Overflow is if you think that content will improve the site. Any other consideration is pointless, and reflects wrong-headed priorities (i.e. "will I get rep for this?"). Failing to post content that would improve the site solely for the reason that you won't "get enough rep for it" completely misses the point of being a member of the community. Posting content that doesn't improve the site, for any reason but certainly also for the purpose of gaining rep, similarly misses the point.

Comment: I'm genuinely interested in helping as many people as possible. If I don't reach a lot of people on question with well established answers my efftorts may be better spent on other questions.

Comment: Believe it or not, there are questions with lots of answers that are incomplete or wrong because either the subject is too deep for most to grasp or the language or best practice has changed over the past decade since the site got started. Almost my entire reputation is built on writing new answers that start out at the bottom, because I focus on creating value with my answers: TLDR at beginning, deeper explanation, examples with best practices, citing relevant parts of docs, source code, and other original sources where apropos, and explanations about errors in other answers or comments.

Comment: @AaronHall - Indeed, what you've described is the essense of [Suragch's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/350410/95852) and the ["most-canonical-answer strategy"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321352/95852).

Answer (score 13):

My primary method of answering questions is adding new answers to old questions. I don't let the number of previous answers stop me as long as I have new information or a better answer to add. It usually takes a year or two but as long as my answer is significantly better than the others, it does move to ([or toward](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326095/please-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top)) the top.

I find this method a much better use of my time compared with answering new questions. It is almost guaranteed to help more people. New questions often fade away into oblivion and are rarely viewed again. Thus, it is hard to know if answering a new question will have any lasting impact. Often it doesn't.

Related: [Most canonical answer strategy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321352/3681880)

Answer (score 8):

I asked myself this question today as I read a question from 2009 and wondered if I should post and answer.  I might go back and do it because the technology has changed, but the question has not.  What was the best answer in PHP 5.2 is not the best answer in PHP 7.1, but the search engines will probably land on that old post before they land on a new one.

Comment: See my answer for why you should do it. I only give two examples. Would love to have you join that list

Answer (score 8):

If you have something to add, or a different angle, then add it.

I can think of two questions where a later answer is better than the accepted/top answer

[MySQL: Grant **all** privileges on database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016505/mysql-grant-all-privileges-on-database)

[Passing an array to a query using a WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907806/passing-an-array-to-a-query-using-a-where-clause)

Both feature top answers with security risks (edits can only take you so far) and subsequent answers that solve the original question while avoiding the security problems.

Incidentally, I have a pet peeve of people parroting answers on canonicals and I actively try to clean the ones I know of so you don't have to always scroll past 20 answers (where half of them are some rehash of a better answer).

Comment: This answer is a bit unnuanced. Keep in mind that writing a good answer _takes time_, and if the goal is to help as many as possible, that time may be better spent on answering questions that don't already have 20+ answers.

Answer (score 5):

The answer depends on if you care most about virtual internet points or if you care about making SO/the internet a better place.

Most users lose their interest in chasing reputation after they get 20k rep or so. **The main motivator for answering questions should be to add quality content.** Especially so high reputation users who have unlocked all site previleges.

If you need to make statistical graphs to calculate effort versus reputation gained in order to see if "answering is worth your time", then you have not understood the true purpose of sites like SO.

---

If internet reputation gambling is oh-so-important, then you can take delight in the fact that by actively participating in the Java tag, you have already secured the best reputation/effort ratio possible, as the tag takes up no less than around [10% of the total posts on SO](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=blog&utm_campaign=trends&utm_content=blog-link&tags=java).

Your answer has currently 110 up votes and you are still not sure if it is worth your time. After which you risk coming across as quite spoiled, by the standards of less popular tags.

The [top user in the Java tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/topusers) has gained 114772 rep points from that tag alone. Compare this with some much less popular language like for example [Ada](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ada/topusers), where the top user has gained 1039 points from tag participation.

Comment: If you had read my entire question including the clarification in the end, you'd known it's not about the rep (as your whole answer seems to assume).